# What partition PlayOnLinux and Wine software has to be installed to?

Tags: wine, disk-usage, playonlinux

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and if I have already created ext4 `./` (partition) and on the same volume I have `./home`

If I create a separate partition `./home` will the software that I install for example from Ubuntu Download Center will automatically go to `./home` (partition) or still `./` (root) ?

I'm using PlayOnLinux and Wine and all its software only installs to `./home` (file system disk) where emulated copy of Windows Xp installed also and it's a lack of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine installs all the stuff in `~/.wine` which translate to `$HOME/.wine` or `/home/user/.wine`. You cannot use systems (anything that's not `/home`) for installing wine application (or more like, you will end up messing up, so please not). You may want to create a new partition and mount it in your `/home/user/.wine` directory instead:

After you have created the new ext4 partition, run `sudo blkid`, it will show something like:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="bf554a2f-a035-4c22-bca8-162def35a03c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="3962db06-3776-4f38-8ab9-eab6feeccc1d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Lets assume `sda2` is your new partition, edit `/etc/fstab` and add the following entry:

```
UUID=3962db06-3776-4f38-8ab9-eab6feeccc1d /home/user/.wine ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Of course, change `user` for your actual username. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're actually asking, but playonlinux itself is installed by the package manager to `/usr/whatever` or some similar directory, so on the partition where your `/` is mounted. The different wine versions and windows applications are installed into `/home/username/.PlayOnLinux` (`.wine` if you use wine directly without playonlinux).

You can move the `.PlayOnLinux` or `.wine` directory whereever you like (as long as the permissions stay the same) and then create a symbolic link to it.

For example if you move your `.Playonlinux` directory to `/mnt/data/` you can create a symbolic link with the following command:

```
ln -s /mnt/data/.PlayOnLinux ~/.PlayOnLinux
```